# UITableView form automatically save

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I've created a UITableView which works as a setting viewcontroller. this means there are different values that i would like to save. I would like to avoid creating a save button and instead just automatically update to my database. I could update every time a value has changed, but that would be a lot of update calls, since it would update every time a char has changed. Is there a smoother way to do this?

i see a lot of different bigger apps which are not using a save button, where it just saves automatically.

Comment: what are the elements your table view contains?

Comment: Different elements. textfields, switch and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create one dictionary and save your all settings into that:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSMutableDictionary * settingsDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary allo]init];
}
```

create one method to save settings into created dictionary

```
-(void)saveSettingValues:(NSString *)setting forKey:(NSString *)key
{

[settingsDictionary addObjectForKey:key];

}
```

call this method on every element status change.for example if textfield value is changed then by using textField delegate method send the value into dictionary

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self saveSettingValues:textField.text forKey:yorKey];
}
```

then send the dictionary where do you want to store the setting values on every call of saveSettingValues:forKey method

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand well your problem but for me you could save data when the viewController will be remove of the screen (application in background or viewcontroller pop).

Comment: @hypo- this should be in comments